# Some of the characters/ fonts are tofu

Tags: fonts, 16.04, special-characters

[image]

Some of them can not be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, just install fonts-noto.

Comment: *"In slang those small boxes have sometimes been called "tofu". Noto as in **no to**fu, aims to remove tofu from the Web. This is how the Noto font families got their name."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts ;)